# Network Requests Throttling in React Class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Supposing that I have a `Search` component that, when the user types something, would fire an API request to look for what is typed. When using React's `useEffect` Hook, it would be easy to throttle the API request's with a combination of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` (which is placed in the clean up function that `useEffect` returns). However, how can this be done in the Class component version of `Search` inside the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method?

```
function Search() {
  const [term, setTerm] = React.useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(term)
      const timeOutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (term)
          (async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get(
              "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
              {
                params: {
                  action: "query",
                  list: "search",
                  origin: "*",
                  format: "json",
                  srsearch: term,
                },
              }
            );

            setResults(data.query.search);
          })();
        }, 500);
      }

    return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [term]);

  return (
    /* some JSX */
  );
}
```

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    term: '',
    results: []
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    /* ??? */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      /* some JSX */
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `componentDidUpdate()` for this, it would be easier to handle most of the logic in the `onChange` handler of your input.

There are two important nuances to get right here. The first is that `timeoutId` should not be in state so it won't trigger any extra renders. The second part is to clean up the timeout after the component unmounts via [`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount), so you won't leave any dangling calls to be made after your component no longer exists.

```js
class Foo extends React.PureComponent {
  timeoutId = undefined;
  state = {
    term: ""
  };
  
  // Note that this method is bound so we can pass it directly to `onChange`
  onTermChange = (event) => {
    if (this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    }
    const term = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ term });
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.timeoutId = undefined;
      console.log(`timer fired with "${term}"`);
    }, 1000);
  };
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onTermChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```